# Accessing CSS Properties inside a Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't think this is possible but I thought I'd ask anyway.

I'm building a Wordpress plugin for sharing buttons and [Buffer](http://bufferapp.com) doesn't have a mechanism to return to the site if you locate in the same window, so I built out a nice popup that will fetch the add link.  This works great except that the buffer add page creates a modal dialog that is positioned 100px from the top.

This creates a nasty 100px space above the dialog. See here:

[image]

I was wondering if it's possible to change the css inside that popup window, or perhaps find a way to have the window directly access just the div with a specific id?

The modal is draggable as well, so maybe create a drag action to drag it up to the top?

Any ideas would be helpful.

--EDIT--

Adding Fiddle as requested.

Not sure what the size of the window will be when you're not logged into Buffer, but you'll get the general idea of how the spacing is messed up at the top ... maybe.

SO won't let me add a fiddle link without code the post is: jsfiddle.net/y6RQ7/6/

Comment: Do you mind creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or host your page on Heroku? I don't think a lot of people will have time to figure out how Buffer works. If your question doesn't need that knowledge, you can remove that part altogether.

Comment: Add a specific CSS file that overrides the buffer settings for that page.  CSS order of precedent is generally by load order (or you could use !important).

Comment: Yes but how to access the new window to override the css property?